# How to see the error when running an SQL script from SQLPlus fails?

Tags: sql, oracle, powershell, sqlplus

I have been able to run an SQL script `script.sql` from within SQL Plus as follows:

```
SQL>@script.sql
```

I did that after starting SQL Plus and logging from within Powershell in as follows:

```
C:\projects\temp> sqlplus myuser/mypassword@my.tns.address
```

Now what I'd like to do is run the script above directly from Powershell. It is my understanding that I should be able to do that like this:

```
C:\projects\temp> sqlplus myuser/mypassword@my.tns.address script.sql
```

I expected this to work fine, especially considering I'm using the same user and password, the same TNS, and calling the same script.

Instead of running the script however, all this command does is output the Help-text for SQL Plus, i.e. the same text that is shown when running `sqlplus -H`.

I'm assuming there is some syntax error, or something else wrong with the command above, but the problem is finding out what that error is.

Is there something obviously wrong with the last command above? Or is there some way for me to turn up the verbosity, so that I can get a hint about what could be wrong?

Comment: [See the section titled "Running a Script as You Start SQL\*Plus" in the SQL*Plus manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#i1210918)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "@" is missing to invoke the script. Try this instead

```
C:\projects\temp> sqlplus myuser/mypassword@my.tns.address @script.sql
```